# Annuity at nominal rate

Tags: finance

Consider a $30$-year loan of  $200,000$ that can be repaid with $A$ per month at a nominal rate of $10$%. Calculate $A$.

Effective monthly interest rate is given as $\frac{0.1}{12}$

Present value of loan is given as

$200 000=A [\frac{1-(\frac{0.1}{12})^{-30X12}}{\frac{0.1}{12}}]$

I am having math error here.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator#Monthly_payment_formula

Answer (score 0):

$A=\frac{200,000(\frac{0.1}{12}) (1+\frac{0.1}{12})^{360}}{(1+\frac{0.1}{12})^{360}-1}=1755.143$